# Are .ui files from qt compatible with both python and c++?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have been working with QT UIs and python for a while now. I have been wondering, if the .ui files that are generated when using the qt-creator or qt-designer are compatible with both python and c++? I mean it is just some simple xml syntax right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer, that I was looking for: Yes .ui files are compatible. They are simple xml syntax files and simply contain the structure of your designed user interface.

Depending on your programming lagnuage, the xml file is parsed, so that you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are simple xmls. The differences could be generated in the tools that convert that xml to C++ or Python (uic for C++ and currently for PySide2, pyuic for PyQt5) since that code interprets the attributes.

Comment: In short, this means that UI files are not directly compatible, but can be converted with appropriate tools?